# How to save durably a file on internal storage

Tags: android, file, save, android-file

I am currently encountering a problem saving a text file on the internal storage.

The problem is that whenever i exit the application, the file seems to be deleted.

I wrote this method that is called at the start of the application, to create a blank text file :

```
private void init() {
    String FILE_NAME = "save.txt";
    try {
        new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(getFilesDir() + FILE_NAME));
        Toast.makeText(this, "GOOD", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

this function is called to read all lines written in it :

```
private List<String> readFromFile() {
    List<String> ret = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(getFilesDir()+"save.txt");
        BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line;
        while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
            ret.add(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, "GOOD", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return ret;
}
```

And finaly this method is called to append a string in the text file if it's not already in it :

```
 private void save(String unNom) {
    String FILE_NAME = "save.txt";
    List<String> ret = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(getFilesDir()+"save.txt");
        BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line;
        while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
            ret.add(line);
        }
        if(!ret.contains(unNom)){
            ret.add(unNom);
        }
        bReader.close();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(getFilesDir() +FILE_NAME);
        for (String ligne: ret) {
            ligne+="\n";
            fos.write(ligne.toString().getBytes());
        }
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "GOOD", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

What should I do to save correctly the file in the internal storage ?

Sorry for my bad english, 
Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The init was'nt necessary. I removed the method and I edited the save method, so it could create a new file if a not found exception was raised :

```
private void save(String unNom) {
    String FILE_NAME = "save.txt";

    List<String> ret = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        InputStream inputStream = openFileInput("save.txt");
        BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        String line;
        while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
            ret.add(line);
        }
        if (!ret.contains(unNom)) {
            ret.add(unNom);
        }
        bReader.close();
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        fos = openFileOutput("save.txt", this.MODE_PRIVATE);
        for (String ligne : ret) {
            ligne = "\n" + ligne;
            fos.write(ligne.getBytes());
        }
        fos.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "GOOD", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        try {
            Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            fos = openFileOutput("save.txt", this.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fos.write(unNom.getBytes());
            fos.close();
            Toast.makeText(this, "NEW FILE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        catch(Exception e2){}
    }
}
```